# $Q\le \prod \frac{5+2x}{1+x}\le P$ find $P,Q$

Tags: inequality, optimization, summation, maxima-minima, products

> if $x,y,z,$ are positives and $x+y+z=1$ and $$Q\le \prod_{cyc} \frac{5+2x}{1+x}\le P$$ find  maximum value of $Q$ and minimum value of $P$

This is actually a question made up myself ,so i don,t know whether a nice solution exists!?.

Finding P seems easier:AM-GM results $$\prod \frac{5+2x}{1+x}\le \frac{{\left(\sum_{cyc} \frac{5+2x}{1+x} \right)}^3}{27}$$

we write $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{5+2x}{1+x}=6+\sum \frac{3}{1+x}$$

But neither Jensen nor the tangent line method help as sign of inequality is reversed.

In fact i am more interested in finding $Q$.

I am looking for  a solution that avoids using computational aid(SOS) or ,uvw.

Comment: why  the downvote?

Comment: Is the product over $x,y,z$? If yes then you trivially have that $Q>9$

Comment: @QC_QAOA yes ,it is over x,y,z.Also i have edited the post

Comment: Maximum value of P does not exist, you want to minimize P.

Comment: @Displayname yes of course ,fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finding Q via Jensen's:**
Let $f(x) = \frac{ 5 + 2x } { 1 + x } $.
Let $ g(x) = \ln \frac{ 5+2x}{1+x} $, then $ g'(x) = - \frac{3}{ 2x^2 + 7x + 5 } $ and $ g'' (x) = \frac{ 3 ( 4x + 7 ) } { (2x^2 + 7x + 5 )^2 }$.
When $ x \geq 0$, $g''(x) \geq 0$, so we may apply Jensens to conclude that

$$ \sum g(x) \geq 3 g ( \frac{1}{3} ).$$

Taking $e$ to the power of both sides, we conclude that

$$ \prod f(x) \geq f(\frac{1}{3} ) ^ 3. $$

Note: The tangent line approach is similar on $g(x)$, and it works because of the condition  $ g''(x) \geq 0$.

---

**Finding P via Step-wise smoothing**
A good guess is that the maximum occurs at the extreme end (which isn't necessarily the case), which others have shown. As such, step-wise smoothing is often good approach.

Claim: When $a,b \geq 0$, $f(a) f(b) \leq f(0 ) f( a+b)$.
This follow by cross multiplying to get $ 6x^2 + 21 xy + 6y^2 \geq 0 $ which is obviously true.

Hence, $f(x)f(y) f(z) \leq f(0)f(x+y)f(z) \leq f(0) f(0) f(x+y+z) = \frac{175}{2}$.
It remains to show that this is indeed the supremum, which you can verify with $ x = y \rightarrow 0^+$.

Note: Karamata's inequality (which is a generalization of Jensen's) also gives this result directly. In fact, the above approach is a specific case of Karamata (but doesn't require as much power).

Comment: agreed ,but i am interested in finding minimum value ie Q of the **product** and not the sum,as you have shown by tangent line method

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Oh, sorry, I misread it. Let me rethink.

Comment: no worries thank you for taking time

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Doesn't Jensen work directly on $g(x) = \ln \frac{5+2x}{1+x}$? We have $g' = - \frac{3}{2x^2 + 7x + 5 } $ and $g'' = \frac{ 3 (4x+7) } { (2x^2 + 7x + 5 ) ^2 } > 0 $.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I've fleshed it out. 1) I'm not sure what you mean by "reverse of AM-GM". 2) There is a negative sign in $g'$. We care that $g'' > 0$.

Comment: yes i see sorry i made a mistake in g' being negative,you are right ,i was thinking in the wrong way.Jensen works and gives Q directly.Thank you so much!

Comment: Also is there a way other than the one M.Rozenberg used to find P?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Sure. It's very similar, just involving convex functions essentially.

Comment: Thanks! i would have loved to accept this answer but i guess its unethical to switch them finnally

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Nothing unethical with switching if you think that another answer is "better". There's tension in "Should I accept a good enough answer quickly, or wait till there is a great answer?"

Answer (score 3):

For $x=y=z=\frac{1}{3}$ we obtain a value $\frac{4913}{64}.$

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, after homogenization we need to prove that
$$\prod_{cyc}\frac{7x+5y+5z}{2x+y+z}\geq\frac{4913}{64}$$ or
$$\sum_{sym}(687x^3+489x^2y-1176xyz)\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM or by Muirhead.

Also, for $y=z\rightarrow0^+$ we obtain a value $\frac{175}{2}.$

We'll prove that it's a supremum of the expression.

Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$\prod_{cyc}\frac{7x+5y+5z}{2x+y+z}\leq\frac{175}{2}$$ or $$\sum_{sym}(135x^2y+94xyz)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: Thats quick!and neat thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, @Albus Dumbledore !

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=y=z=\frac 13$ then $Q \leqslant \frac{4913}{64}.$ We will show that it's a maximum value, or
$$(5x+5y+7z)(5z+5x+7y)(5y+5z+7x) \geqslant \frac{4913}{64}(2x+y+z)(2y+z+x)(2z+x+y).$$
Let
$$\left\{\begin{aligned} & a = 2x+y+z\\& b = 2y+z+x \\& c = 2z+x+y\end{aligned}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{aligned} & x = \frac{3a-b-c}{4} \\& y = \frac{3b-c-a}{4} \\& z = \frac{3c-a-b}{4}\end{aligned}\right.$$
The inequality become
$$(11c+3b+3a)(3c+11b+3a)(3c+3b+11a) \geqslant 4913abc.$$
Using the AM-GM inequality, we have
$$(11a+3b+3c)(11b+3c+3a)(11c+3a+3b) \geqslant 17^3 \cdot \sqrt[17]{a^{11}b^3c^3} \cdot \sqrt[17]{b^{11}c^3a^3} \cdot \sqrt[17]{c^{11}a^3b^3} $$
$$= 4913abc.$$

Comment: very nice substituition!